# react-autocomplete lazy load datatlist in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, database, autocomplete, menu, lazy-loading

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete which is working fine

But when the data size increases it takes long time to show the menu

The current implementation is as shown below

```
<div mr-eye-widget-type="TextField">
  <Autocomplete
    ref={el => (this.input = el)}
    value={this.state.value}
    inputProps={inputProps}
    wrapperStyle={{ position: "absolute", display: "inline-block" }}
    items={this.state.srnList}
    getItemValue={item => item.name}
    shouldItemRender={matchSRN}
    autoHighlight={true}
    onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
    onSelect={value => this.onSelectSRN({ value })}
    renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => (
      <div
        className="menu"
        style={{ background: isHighlighted ? "#e1e1e1" : "white" }}
        key={item.code}
      >
        {item.name}
      </div>
    )}
  />
</div>;
```

The total size of the records is 15000

**Question**: Is there a way to load 1000 records and on search load the complete set of records?

please let me know how to configure it I tried to do it as shown below

```
componentDidMount () {
  // Focus the input and select "world"
  this.input.focus();
  this.input.setSelectionRange(6, 11);
}
```

But no luck. Please help